# position of a point in circle's arc matlab

Tags: matlab, geometry

i have a circle and a point on it in `matlab` :

```
center = [Xc1 Yc1];
circle = [center 150];
point=[ 54.8355  116.6433]
```

I want to partition this circle into 8 arc and find out which arc is this point in ? how can i do this in matlab?
(i used this code to draw circle :
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7844-geom2d/content/geom2d/geom2d/intersectLineCircle.m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing a circle into 8 arcs can be stated another way: cutting a pie into 8 pieces. These pie pieces each have an angle of `360/8 = 45` degrees. You can then think of the circle being broken up into these angle ranges (in degrees):

```
[0,45)
[45,90)
[90,135)
[135,180)
[180,225)
[225,270)
[270,315)
[315,0)
```

You'll have to then calculate the angle between the line that is made when you connect your point to the center of the circle and the x-axis. When you calculate this angle, you'll see which 'angle bin' it belongs to.

Comment: just to complete the above answer. first create a matrix with the above information (lets call it M). Then use P = atan2d(point(2)-Yc1Y,point(1)-Xc1) to get the angle, and then make P>=M(:,1) & P<M(:,2)

Comment: To use solution from @ASantosRibeiro, you probably want to change that bottom right element to 360.

Comment: thank you so much ASantosRibeiro!its the best answer :)